# Vim: Aligning insertion point with left side of column

Tags: vim, multiple-columns, indentation

Suppose I have this (where my insertion point is designated "|"):

```
col1           col2

thing          oeueaoue|
another
something
test
```

What keystroke(s) would I use so the insertion point jumps to here:

```
col1           col2

thing          oeueaoue
another        |
something
test
```

?

Is <kbd>return</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>… the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are many lines to edit, it can be useful to map the return key temporarily, something like that in your case:

```
inoremap <buffer> <cr> <esc>jA<tab>
```

When you're done, just cancel the map:

```
iunmap <buffer> <cr>
```

Comment: This solution is very close, but unfortunately it assumes col. 1 has a fixed width.

Comment: You can make tries with mappings like `inoremap <buffer> <cr> <esc>j30|i`, after settting `:set ve=all` (and replacing `30` by the wanted col)

Answer (score -1):

In insert mode:

```
<Down><Tab>
```

In normal mode:

```
<Down>A<Tab>
```

or:

```
j<Tab>
```

Comment: `j` in insert mode?!

Comment: Woops! Corrected.